# Default author or category filter for user group

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I have a bunch of manager user groups that each have article create/edit/delete permissions for a specific category. But when they login to the backend, all articles from all categories display (altho they are greyed out and not selectable). Is there a way to set a default author or category filter for an individual user or group so they only see articles in the category they're allowed to work in?  Or any other way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think Joomla 1.7 has that feature, also you better add a user manager component, that will do the work for you.

Try these plugins these may help you : http://geminorum.ir/joomla/gauthor